# Comp tableview got duplicated when segue back from Dft tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Can someone tell me which part of my code is not correct?

There two two files CompDftVC.swift and SelectDftVC.swift, when clock at tableview (CompDftVC) which segue to another tableview (SelectDftVC), which I make some selection and click 'Save' to segue back, then I got duplicate records at the initial tableview.  Please see my code and screen shots as attached.  Thank you for your help.

```
//  CompDftVC.swift

import UIKit
import Firebase


class CompDftVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return compNDftLst.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = compDftTV.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "compDftTVCell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = compNDftLst[indexPath.row].compName
        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .white
        } else {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .white
        }
        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // pass compID to destination
        tmpComponentId = compNDftLst[indexPath.row].compId!
        // animate effect
        compDftTV.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        // segue triggered
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToSelectDft", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segueToSelectDft" {
            let svc = segue.destination as! SelectDftVC
            svc.passInCompId = tmpComponentId
            svc.passInParentEmpty = tmpParentEmpty
        }


    }

    @IBOutlet weak var compDftTV: UITableView!

    let node = currCompID+"CompDft"
    let compNode = currCompID+"Comp"
    let dftNode = currCompID+"Dft"

    var compNDftLst =  [CompNDft]()
    var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?
    var compRef: DatabaseReference!
    var tmpComponentId = String()
    var tmpParentEmpty = Int()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        compDftTV.delegate = self
        compDftTV.dataSource = self

        self.compNDftLst.removeAll()

        // check whether the compDft table is empty
        // if empty only return component with section (one row)
        // if not, prepare tmp Array to display on tableview

        compRef = Database.database().reference().child(node)
        compRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // need to consider the workshop is still empty or not?
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                // CompDft table is not empty.  need to retrieve comp/defect list and present them at an expandable tableview
//                self.compNDftLst.removeAll()
                // component already has defects.  prepare the tablewview with defect list
                self.tmpParentEmpty = 0
                self.compRef = Database.database().reference().child(self.compNode)
                self.compRef.observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                        for comp in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                            let compObj = comp.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                            self.tmpComponentId = comp.key
                            let componentName = compObj?["name"]
                            let component = CompNDft(compId: self.tmpComponentId as String?, compName: componentName as! String?, dftList: [""])
                            self.compNDftLst.append(component)
                        }
                        self.compDftTV.reloadData()
                    }
                })

            } else {
                // CompDft table is empty.  Only need to get componment list from Comp table
                self.tmpParentEmpty = 1
                self.compRef = Database.database().reference().child(self.compNode)
                self.compRef.observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
//                        self.compNDftLst.removeAll()
                        for comp in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                            let compObj = comp.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                            self.tmpComponentId = comp.key
                            let componentName = compObj?["name"]
                            let component = CompNDft(compId: self.tmpComponentId as String?, compName: componentName as! String?, dftList: [""])
                            self.compNDftLst.append(component)
                        }
                        self.compDftTV.reloadData()
                    }
                })
            }
        })


    } // ViewDidLoad


} // class



//  SelectDftVC.swift

import UIKit
import Firebase

class SelectDftVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tmpDisplayDefectNameList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = selectDftTV.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dftListTVCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = tmpDisplayDefectNameList[indexPath.row]
        // get the componet ID and check which defect was selected and then mark them .checkmark
        if tmpDefectSelected[indexPath.row] == 1 {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .white
        } else {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .white
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark {
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
            tmpDefectSelected[indexPath.row] = 0
        } else {
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
            tmpDefectSelected[indexPath.row] = 1
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
         return 1
     }


    let node = currCompID+"CompDft"
    let compNode = currCompID+"Comp"
    let dftNode = currCompID+"Dft"

    var passInCompId = String()
    var passInParentEmpty = Int()

    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var ref2: DatabaseReference!
    var ref3: DatabaseReference!
    var ref4: DatabaseReference!
    var ref5: DatabaseReference!
    var ref6: DatabaseReference!
    var refDft: DatabaseReference!

    var selectedDft: DatabaseReference!

    var selectedDftId = [String]()

    var tmpDefectSelected = [Int]()
    var initialTmpDefectSelected = [Int]()
    var tmpDisplayDefectIdList = [String]()
    var tmpDisplayDefectNameList = [String]()
    var tmpSelectedDftID = [String]()
    var tmpSelectedDftName = [String]()

    var hasData = Int()

    @IBOutlet weak var selectDftTV: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        selectDftTV.delegate = self
        selectDftTV.dataSource = self

        tmpDisplayDefectIdList.removeAll()  // defect ID
        tmpDisplayDefectNameList.removeAll()  // defect Name
        selectedDftId.removeAll()           // Selected defect ID
        tmpDefectSelected.removeAll()       // Integer array for checkmark
        initialTmpDefectSelected.removeAll() // Initial Integer array for checkmark (to be updated when populating tableview



        if passInParentEmpty == 1 {
            // component doesn't contain any defect
            ref = Database.database().reference().child(dftNode)
            ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                // need to consider the workshop is still empty or not?
                if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                    // get defect list
                    for defect in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                        let defectObj = defect.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                        let defectId = defect.key
                        let defectName = defectObj?["name"]
                        self.tmpDisplayDefectIdList.append(defectId)
                        self.tmpDisplayDefectNameList.append(defectName as! String)
                        self.tmpDefectSelected.append(0)
                        self.initialTmpDefectSelected.append(0)
                    }
                    self.prepareSelectedDftList()
                }
            })
        } else {
            // the component already contain defect
            ref = Database.database().reference().child(dftNode)
            ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                // need to consider the workshop is still empty or not?
                if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                    // get defect list
                    for defect in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                        let defectObj = defect.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                        let defectId = defect.key
                        let defectName = defectObj?["name"]
                        self.tmpDisplayDefectIdList.append(defectId)
                        self.tmpDisplayDefectNameList.append(defectName as! String)
                        self.tmpDefectSelected.append(0)
                        self.initialTmpDefectSelected.append(0)
                    }
                }

                self.ref2 = Database.database().reference().child(self.node)
                self.ref2.queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: self.passInCompId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                        self.hasData = 1
                    } else {
                        self.hasData = 0
                    }
                    if self.hasData == 1 {
                        self.ref3 = Database.database().reference().child(self.node)
                        self.ref3.queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: self.passInCompId).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                                // selected component has defects
                                for child in snapshot.children {
                                    let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                                    let tmpkey = snap.key as String?
                                    self.selectedDftId.append(tmpkey!)
                                }
                            }
                            self.prepareSelectedDftList()
                        })
                    } else {
                        self.prepareSelectedDftList()
                    }

                })
//                self.ref2.removeAllObservers()
            }) // first DBquery
//            self.ref.removeAllObservers()
        }

    }  // viewDidLoad

    @IBAction func saveSelectedDft(_ sender: Any) {

        // prepare the array of defects to be marked for component which can override the current one


        if tmpDisplayDefectNameList.count > 0 {
            for i in 0...tmpDisplayDefectNameList.count - 1 {
                if tmpDefectSelected[i] == 1 {
                    // prepare selected defect ID and name array
                    tmpSelectedDftID.append(tmpDisplayDefectIdList[i])
                    tmpSelectedDftName.append(tmpDisplayDefectNameList[i])
                }
            }

            markUsed4CompNDft()


//            refDft.removeAllObservers()
        }


        // segue back and refresh tmp array (may be) and tableview
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    } // saveSelectedDftBtn

    func prepareSelectedDftList() {
        if selectedDftId.count == 0 {
            selectDftTV.reloadData()
        } else if selectedDftId.count == 1 {
            for i in 0...tmpDisplayDefectIdList.count - 1 {
                if tmpDisplayDefectIdList[i] == selectedDftId[0] {
                    tmpDefectSelected[i] = 1
                    initialTmpDefectSelected[i] = 1
                }
            }
            selectDftTV.reloadData()
        } else if selectedDftId.count > 1 {
            for i in 0...tmpDisplayDefectIdList.count - 1 {
                for j in 0...selectedDftId.count - 1 {
                    if tmpDisplayDefectIdList[i] == selectedDftId[j] {
                        tmpDefectSelected[i] = 1
                        initialTmpDefectSelected[i] = 1
                    }
                }
            }
//            self.ref.removeAllObservers()
            selectDftTV.reloadData()
        }

    }  // prepareSelectedDftList

    func resetComponentUsedToZero() {
        var clearCompId = String()
        var clearCompName = String()
        ref5 = Database.database().reference()
        ref5.child(compNode).queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: passInCompId).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let key = snap.key
                if key == "id" {
                    clearCompId = snap.value as! String
                }
                if key == "name" {
                    clearCompName = snap.value as! String
                }
            }
            let updatedComponent = [
                "id" : clearCompId,
                "name" : clearCompName,
                "date" : utcDate(),
                "time" : utcTime(),
                "updated" : currUID,
                "used" : 0
                ] as [String: Any]

            self.ref5.child(self.compNode).child(self.passInCompId).setValue(updatedComponent)
        })
        ref5.removeAllObservers()
    }

    func setComponentUsedToOne() {
        var clearCompId = String()
        var clearCompName = String()
        ref5 = Database.database().reference()
        ref5.child(compNode).queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: passInCompId).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let key = snap.key
                if key == "id" {
                    clearCompId = snap.value as! String
                }
                if key == "name" {
                    clearCompName = snap.value as! String
                }
            }
            let updatedComponent = [
                "id" : clearCompId,
                "name" : clearCompName,
                "date" : utcDate(),
                "time" : utcTime(),
                "updated" : currUID,
                "used" : 1
                ] as [String: Any]

            self.ref5.child(self.compNode).child(self.passInCompId).setValue(updatedComponent)
        })
        ref5.removeAllObservers()
    }

    func markUsed4CompNDft() {
        ref6 = Database.database().reference()
        // check any changes made
        if initialTmpDefectSelected != tmpDefectSelected {
            if tmpSelectedDftID.count == 0 {
                // clear all defect
                ref6.child(node).child(passInCompId).setValue(nil)

                // should change component 'used' to 0
                resetComponentUsedToZero()
            } else {
                ref6.child(node).child(passInCompId).setValue(nil)
                for i in 0...tmpSelectedDftID.count - 1 {
                    ref6.child(node).child(passInCompId).child(tmpSelectedDftID[i]).setValue(tmpSelectedDftName[i])
                }
                // mark component used = 1
                setComponentUsedToOne()

                // mark defect(s) used = 1

                if tmpSelectedDftID.count > 0 {
                    //                        ref = Database.database().reference().child(dftNode)
                    ref4 = Database.database().reference().child(dftNode)
                    for i in 0...tmpSelectedDftID.count - 1 {
                        ref4.queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: tmpSelectedDftID[i]).observe(.childAdded, with: { (sp) in
                            self.ref4.child(self.tmpSelectedDftID[i]).updateChildValues(["date" : utcDate()])
                            self.ref4.child(self.tmpSelectedDftID[i]).updateChildValues(["time" : utcTime()])
                            self.ref4.child(self.tmpSelectedDftID[i]).updateChildValues(["updated" : currUID])
                            self.ref4.child(self.tmpSelectedDftID[i]).updateChildValues(["used" : 1])
                        })
                    }
                }
                //                    ref4.removeAllObservers()
            }
        }

    } // markUsed4CompNDft

} // class
```

[image: 1st tableview]
[image: 2nd tableview]
[image: segue back and 1st tableview got duplicate rocords]

Comment: I'm sorry it seems I didn't attach screen shots properly.   The last three lines are the url for the screenshots.

Comment: Lines referring to images must not be indented.

Comment: well when your data is reload then first clear the old values means clear the array and it will work fine. The duplicate value is come because there is already old value or old response in array.
Hope you will understand. 
Thank you

Comment: In CompDftVC.swift viewDidLoad I do have the statement to clear the old values, or I should clear the old values some where else?  Would you give me should hints?  Thank you.